# Send function output as an email in IBM cloud functions

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I have following code which gives me a csv file:

```
def main(args):
    data = get_data()
    csv_output = get_csv_file_data(data)
    return {'body': csv_output.getvalue(),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=myfilename.csv'}}
```

Is there a way in IBM cloud that I can send this CSV file as an email within a function?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Cloud does not provide an email service as part of its platform services (IBM Cloud cata), but you could use SendGrid, either directly [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) or through the [classic infrastructure services on IBM Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/classic/services/emaildelivery).

This code sample, [OpenWhisk Contact](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/openwhisk-contact), uses SendGrid for sending out email with IBM Cloud Functions.

Comment: Can we use any email provider? Like Amazon SES with IBM Functions?

Comment: You can use any email provider. The function / action would connect to the SMTP server and send out the email.